NGINX and Vaadin or other services
Hello i've built an iredmail server, with the default Nginx conf that run the webapp on 80 and 443 ports.
I was wandering if it is possible to start a Vaadin service on a different port and use Nginx to proxy the request with specific subdomain to the Vaadin.
I've tried to use ipv6 Nginx side but i can't connect via browser (port 80 and 443 open)
EDIT:
ipv6 part:
NGINX CODE
# HTTPS
server {
    #listen 443  ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443  ssl http2;
    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access1.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error1.log;

    include /etc/nginx/templates/misc.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/ssl.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/iredadmin.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/roundcube.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/sogo.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/netdata.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/php-catchall.tmpl;
    include /etc/nginx/templates/stub_status.tmpl;
}


Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

@cfrick Thank you. i've added it, theres nothing on access1.log and error1.log

Is it working with ipv4? If not, then first debug this one. And we don't see any proxy settings in your nginx. Google for it, there are sites describing it

Yes it works in ipv4. I was wandering if it is possible with a proxy to connect a Java service but I've abandoned this way because i think it is not possible. So I've tried to use ipv6 since I've a block of ips. With ipv4 it works. Ipv4 + proxy does not work

Have you checked the documentation? https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/
